# Let $(G,\circ)$ be a finite group with an identity element $e$ ...

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $H$ is a non-empty subset of $G$ ($H \subseteq G$) with the property $x, y ∈ H \Rightarrow x \circ y \in H$ shows $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

The part that I'm mainly stuck on is that I'm not sure how to show $e \in H$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!! When writing mathematical expressions you must use MathJax to render the math correctly.

Comment: @manooooh Hiiiiiiiiiiii...I agree with you. I'm very happy to meet you here.

Comment: @Sebastiano heyyyy, it has been a long time since we didn't match! Nice to see you here.

Comment: You should have your whole question in the body. Right now, part of it is in the title, which increases the chance of misunderstading.

Comment: @manooh Thanks for the heads up; I'm relatively new to this so I don't really know what MathJax is yet but I'll keep that in mind for future reference :)

Comment: @verret Yeah I didn't like the way I set it up either. The limit for the question was 150 characters which was too long to fit. I'm completely new to this so I didn't know how it would show up to the viewer but I'll do that next time.

Comment: I didn't expect responses to come this quickly but thanks to everyone who answered and I did figure it out

Comment: I don't think there is a character limit for questions?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that $H$ is finite is crucial.

Since $H$ is not empty, choose $y\in H$ and consider the map $\mu_y\colon H\to H$ defined by $\mu_y(x)=xy$. This is well defined (in particular the codomain is $H$) by assumption.

The map is injective<sup>1</sup>, so also surjective because $H$ is finite. Then there exists $x\in H$ such that $\mu_y(x)=xy=y$. Since we're in a group $G$, this implies $x=e$. Therefore $e\in H$.

Now, for the same reason, there exists $z\in H$ such that $\mu_y(z)=zy=e$. Then $z=y^{-1}\in H$. Since this holds for *any*  $y\in H$, you're done.

---

<sup>1</sup> If $\mu_y(a)=\mu_y(b)$, then $ay=by$. We can multiply both sides by $y^{-1}$ and get $a=b$. You don't need to know that $y^{-1}\in H$, at this point: the relation $ay=by$ holds for $a,b,y\in G$ and $G$ is a group.

Comment: Your comment actually helped me understand this problem much more conceptually. I wouldn't have thought of this problem in the context of mapping

Answer (score 1):

$H$ is nonempty so it contains some element $x$. Therefore, by the property $H$ satisfies we have $x^2 \in H$. Either $x^2$ is the identity, or $x^2$ is not the identity in which case we look at all possible products of elements we know are in $H$. This process must terminate since $H$ is a finite set, so $e$ must be in $H$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Since $G$ is finite, for each $x \in H$ there exists some $n \geq 1$ such that 
$$x^n=e$$

Show that $x \in H$ implies that $x^n \in H$.

Comment: I know you didn't intend to give the full answer, but this definitely helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

With

$\emptyset \ne H \subset G, \tag 1$

and $H$ *multiplicatively closed*, which is simply another way of saying

$\forall x, y \in H, \; x \circ y \in H, \tag 2$

we have

$\exists x \in H; \tag 3$

by (2),

$x^2 = x \circ x \in H, \; x^3 = x \circ x^2 \in H, \tag 4$

and in fact

$\forall m \in \Bbb N, \; x^m \in H, \tag 5$

which may in fact be proved by a simple induction:  taking (4) as the basis, we assume

$x^k \in H; \tag 6$

then by (2),

$x^{k + 1} = x \circ x^k \in H \tag 7$

as well; thus (5) binds.

Now since

$\vert G \vert = n < \infty, \tag 8$

$\exists m \in \Bbb N, \; x^m = 1; \tag 9$

this is easily seen by observing that the sequence of powers of $x$,

$x, \; x^2, \; x^3, \ldots \tag{10}$

must at some point begin to repeat itself in light of (8); that is,

$\exists k, l \in \Bbb N, \; k < l, \; x^l = x^k; \tag{11}$

then

$x^{l - k} = x^l x^{-k} = x^k x^{-k} = e, \tag{12}$

so we may take

$m = l - k. \tag{13}$

We may now affirm that, in light of (5),

$e = x^m \in H; \tag{14}$

furthermore, if $m = 1$,

$e^{-1} = e \in H, \tag{15}$

whilst with $m > 1$

$x \ast x^{m - 1} = x^m = e, \tag{16}$

which shows that

$x^{-1} = x^{m - 1} \in H. \tag{11}$

We thus see that $H$, in addition to satisfying (2), contains both $e$ and the invere of each of its elements; thus we conclude that $H$ is in fact a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: I don't like this approach. The fact that $G$ is finite is irrelevant: it's sufficient to assume that $H$ is finite. My preferred proof needs no reference to powers and is just based on the pigeonhole principle.